# How to justify label text?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

My code to justify label text is given below:-

```
-(void)justifyToLabel:(UILabel*)label withStr:(NSString*)str{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyles.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;
    NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles};
    NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: str attributes: attributes];
    label.attributedText = attributedString;
}
```

I don't know that why its not working. Please give a best solution.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean not working? What's the result?

Comment: means label alignment is not set in square justify mannar. Label text are showing as like before using this code and also i want to clarify that i am using iOS 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the below code:

You have not assigned any value to `firstLineHeadIndent` property, that's why it is not working.

```
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyles = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyles.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;      //justified text
paragraphStyles.firstLineHeadIndent = 1.0;                //must have a value to make it work

NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName: paragraphStyles};
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString: string attributes: attributes];

label.attributedText = attributedString;
```

Comment: Best of luck for future & Happy Coding. :) (y)

Comment: @ChaubeyJi What are you doing exactly can you explain?